# Latest bid in Excel from Bloomberg Quote Recap on specific time

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

Latest Bid/Ask on Quote Recap on specific time. Example
[image: Example]

I am trying to use the open Bloomberg API to gather the latest bid/ask on a specific date for a specific time.

But with this formula:

```
=BDH("XS1001668950"& " "&"@BGN"&" CORP ISIN";"Last Price";"07/10/2018 09:03:04 AM";"07/10/2018 09:03:04 AM";"BarTp=b;BarSz=1;Fill=P";"cols=2;rows=1")
```

I get `100.568` instead of `103.668` in bid and `104.034` instead of `104.027`.

How can I get the latest bid in Quote Recap on a specific time?

Comment: If you remove `Fill=P` you will see that the request doesn't return anything. Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site. What do you mean about have I asked HELP HELP?

Comment: pressing F1 (help) twice on your keyboard while on the bloomberg terminal opens a chat with Bloomberg's help desk.

Comment: The answer to find best bid from a specifik pricing source quote is: =BDH(DK0004915436& " "@CBBT" CORP ISIN";"Last Price";"07/16/2018 13:58:00";"07/16/2018 13:58:01";"BarTp=B,BarSz=1,Fill=P";"cols=2;rows=1")

Comment: You can answer your own question below to help future readers.